# Mongoose update and find object in multidimentional array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

Im trying to get one of my user`s by the following query:

```
pokertable.findOne({ _id: gameid }, { "players.$.userid": userid })
```

but that wont execute. How come?

Im also looking for a way to update the user the same way, is that the same approatch?

Model:

```
  pot_history: {
        type: Array
    },
    players : [
        {
            userid: {
                type: String,
                default: 0,
            },
            username: {
                type: String,
                default: 'ukjent',
            },
            last_perform: {
                type: Number,
                default: 0,
            },

            cash: {
                type: Number,
                default: 0,
            },

            hands_history: {
                type: Array,
            },
        }
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

For find use the query:

```
pokertable.findOne({ _id: gameid, "players.userid": userid });
```

And for update the same:

```
 pokertable.update({ _id: gameid, "players.userid": userid }, {"players.$.userid": newUserid});
```

Comment: is there a way i can get the object of user itself, and not the entire result? :)

Comment: Yes, you can use pokertable.findOne({ _id: gameid, "players.userid": userid }, {"players.$.userid":1});

Comment: now i get http://prntscr.com/cyc7qu
is it possible to get the entire user there? or do i have to 'walk' into the array from here?

Comment: Can you put your schema and query that you run over here?

Comment: its the same query you gave me. updating entire model

Comment: If you want to get entire use in the userid field then you have to refer user collection (by using  ref) in your schema and then use populate to get entire user data. please refer this link http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html